# Getting Error code 403 while accessing Office 365 mail box for the client credential grant flow

Tags: ms-office, office365, office365-apps

I am trying to connect to Office 365 to use the client credential flow.I have followed all the steps as mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx

I am trying to connect using the ADAL java library.

Using the below code to connect and fetch mail:

```
String authority = "https://login.windows.net/tenant-id/oauth2/authorize";
ExecutorService service = null;
service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
try {
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =  new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, service);
    String certfile = "PfxFinal.pfx";
    InputStream pkcs12Certificate=new FileInputStream(certfile);

    String token = "";

    AsymmetricKeyCredential credential = AsymmetricKeyCredential.create("clientid", pkcs12Certificate,"password");
    System.out.println("X509 is fine!");

    Future<AuthenticationResult> future=authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", (AsymmetricKeyCredential)credential, null);// authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", credential, null);
    System.out.println("Token Received "+future.get().getAccessToken());
    token=future.get().getAccessToken();
    System.out.println(token);


    URL url = new URL("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/inbox/messages?$count=true&$filter=isread%20eq%20false");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
    con.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json"); 
    //con.setRequestProperty("Authorization",token);
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+token);
    System.out.println("Bearer "+token);

    if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + con.getResponseCode());
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (con.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    con.disconnect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have given the full permission for the tenant.Is there anything else , that I have to do in order to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are addressing the "/me" endpoint, which for "app-only" access has really no meaning as "me" represents a mailbox and the access token has no user context that could be used to determine what "me" mailbox is attempted to access. For app-only access token you must use users('the mailbox e-mail address to access'). "app-only" represents an application identity with no information about mailboxes or users.

Let me know if you still have issues.

Thanks,
Matthias

Comment: Hi Matthias , I have now added the below url for invoking the list of messages from the inbox : https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/emailaddress/folders/inbox/messages .  However , I am now getting now error code 400. Is this line correct : con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+token); or this should be con.setRequestProperty("Authorization",token);

Comment: You need to set the header as "Authorization: Bearer token". In the 400 do you get some additional information back in some headers? E.g. do you see a x-ms-diagnostics header? Could you copy&paste the access token to http://jwt.calebb.net and check what is in the "roles" claim-type.

Comment: The roles for the access token are "full_access_as_app",
"Mail.Read","Mail.Send" . I am not getting x-ms-diagnostics in the header .

Comment: Below is the header information ,by con.getHeaderFields():
{null=
[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized], 
WWW-Authenticate=[Basic Realm=""], 
Content-Length=[0], 
request-id=[305f6089-026f-43d7], 
Set-Cookie=[ClientId=HVVBULC0A; 
expires=Thu, 26-May-2016 10:59:35 GMT; 
path=/; 
secure; HttpOnly],
 X-WSSecurity-X509Cert-Enabled=[True], 
 Server=[Microsoft-IIS/8.0], 
 X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], 
 X-OAuth-Enabled=[True], 
 X-FederationTrustTokenIssuerUri=[urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline],
 X-WSSecurity-For=[Logon], 
 X-FEServer=[SGR03],  
 X-WSSecurity-SymmetricKey-Enabled=[True],
 X-WSSecurity-Enabled=[True]}

Comment: Also , as per your blog , when uploading the manifest file , with the $base64Value_from_above under "keyCredentials", for value , it becomes null when I re download it to verify. I am able to upload with all the details, though.Is this expeceted? And finally , while registering the web app, in the azure management portal , I had given a standard web url (like gmail), for the app url id , instead of a custom one , since I havent got any url yet . Is there any standard url that we can use , before creating an web url of our own. will this be a problem , if I do this this way?

Comment: That's all ok regards the value from the manifest is not set and a app id uri that is not final. For all that matters the app id uri is not used for OAuth2. I usually fill it with https://<any of my verified domains>/<myappname>.

Comment: What's not ok is the headers you are getting back do not include a www-authenticate: bearer. This seems to indicate  that there is something wrong with the authorization header submitted with the request. Any chance you can send me the a complete fiddler trace, e.g. remove the access token from the fiddler, or just wait one hour before you send it to me, so the access token is not valid anymore. My e-mail is: mattleib@microsoft.com

Comment: Thanks . This is solved by fixing the Authorization header, and changing the url , by adding /users/ before the email address. We are able to fetch data by making the rest calls.

Answer (score 0):

What Exchange Online permissions did you configure when you registered the application in Azure AD? You should have either `Read mail in all mailboxes` or `Read and write mail in all mailboxes`.

Comment: I had actually given both the access , Read and Read/Write . I have given the Read Write access only now.Also , as suggested by Mathias , I have replaced the /me by an actual email address. However , I am getting a error 400 now. Wondering if the line con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); is correct . When I remove the Bearer , then I am getting a Error 401.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved and below is a full working code:

public class AccessToken {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String authority = "https://login.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/authorize";
ExecutorService service = null;
service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
try {
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext =  new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, service);
    String certfile = "pfx.pfx";
    InputStream pkcs12Certificate=new FileInputStream(certfile);

    String token = "";


    AsymmetricKeyCredential credential = AsymmetricKeyCredential.create("id", pkcs12Certificate,"password");
    System.out.println("X509 is fine!");

    Future<AuthenticationResult> future=authenticationContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office365.com", (AsymmetricKeyCredential)credential, null);

    token=future.get().getAccessToken();

    Long uuid = UUID.randomUUID().getMostSignificantBits();


    URL url = new URL("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/email/folders/inbox/messages");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 

    con.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Testing/1.0 abc/1.1");
    Date date = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat ft = 
              new SimpleDateFormat ("E, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz");

              System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(date));
              String dateString = ft.format(date);



    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer "+token);


    if (con.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        System.out.println(con.getHeaderFields());

        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + con.getResponseCode());

    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (con.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    con.disconnect();

    service.shutdown();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

I am able to get the json response from office 365. Another way I tested was using the RestClient plugin of Firefox , with the generated Access Token.